# Jquery/JS scoping

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may be pretty simple but it's stumping me. I'm trying to return a variable in javascript to another variable outside of the function's scope. For some reason, the assignment isn't occurring. Here's my code:

```
var time = Math.round(((new Date()).getTime())/1000);

// first call to get data
var power_now = get_data(<%= @user.id %>, time);

function get_data(user_id, timestamp){
  var targetURL = "get/user_data?time_now="+timestamp+"&user_id="+user_id;
  var power = 0;

  $.get(targetURL, function(data){
    power = data[0]['power'];
    alert(power);
  })

  return power;
}

$('body').html('<h1>'+power_now+','+power_then+'</h1>')
```

If I place alert(power) within the .get function, the value is correct; however if I place it outside of the .get function, the value is 0.

Maybe I'm missing something about scoping in javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Why bind `@user.id` twice when you're passing it into the `get_data` function? And you're passing in `timestamp` and not using that either.

Comment: You're right. Functionally the same; I was refactoring some code so forgot to use the variables passed in. Editing response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get` is a synonym for `.ajax` with some specific parameters set.  The first A in AJAX is Asynchronous.  This means that the code is not executed immediately, it sends off the request and moves on.  Therefore the assignment of that variable does not occur until after the return statement.

Instead, you should move the code into the callback:

```
$.get(targetURL, function(data){
    power = data[0]['power'];

    $('body').html('<h1>'+power_now+','+power_then+'</h1>')
})
```

Comment: There is another option, though I will not put it into my answer as it is rarely a good idea.  If you change your `get` to `ajax` then you can set `async : false`, which will cause the code to wait for a response.  This is almost always a bad idea as the browser will hang while waiting for a response.

Comment: I'd like to call the function more than once to GET data, then assign it to multiple variables within my script. So, for instance, power_now and power_then have different timestamps. In your method, I'd have to make the assignment and update whatever component needs updating inline with the .get function. Is there any other way to invoke this method when needed? Maybe making it synchronous but I understand why that's bad ...

Comment: If you need to wait until multiple calls have returned, you could use jquery's `when`  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` is an aysc AJAX call meaning the function will return 0 even before the server has responded.

You need to use a callback function to set the `power_now` or call the respective code.

You can modify your code like below if it works for you,

```
var power_now = 0;
get_data(<%= @user.id %>, time);

function get_data(user_id, timestamp){
  var targetURL = "get/user_data?time_now="+time+"&user_id="+<%= @user.id %>;

  $.get(targetURL, function(data){
    power_now = data[0]['power'];
    $('body').html('<h1>'+power_now+','+power_then+'</h1>')
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` is an asynchronous ajax call.  You need to specify the resulting action in the success function.

```
var time = Math.round(((new Date()).getTime())/1000);

// first call to get data
var power_now = get_data(<%= @user.id %>, time);

function get_data(user_id, timestamp){
  var targetURL = "get/user_data?time_now="+time+"&user_id="+<%= @user.id %>;
  var power = 0;

  $.get(targetURL, function(data){
    power = data[0]['power'];
    alert(power);
  })

  .success(function() { $('body').html('<h1>'+power+','+power_then+'</h1>') })
}
```